# Windows Search (Windows Desktop Search) wildcards do not work

Tags: windows-search, wildcards

At our company we have a big source code repository, and sometimes we need to do searches through all the code. As we need that from time to time we want to do something simple. I've tried Windows Search indexing over XP but it looks like wildcards are not working (something strange for a search system).

If I search for UserName or for ExtendedUserName I get different results and if I use *UserName I don't get results at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/) is wonderful for this

[Other possibilities](http://alternativeto.net/software/astrogrep/)

Comment: Ops, the problem with AstroGrep is that it does not indexes contents and searchs are waaaaaaaaaay slower than with Desktop search ... anyway can be useful in some restricted scenarios.